# invalid type sobject type ApexClass is not supported

Tags: managed-package, custom-button

I'm in a test org where I've installed my managed package. I have a javascript button that is utilizing the AJAX Toolkit to get the namespace dynamically but its not working in this org (it works fine in others) I'm getting the error:

`..invalid type sobject type ApexClass is not supported...`

The error is verbose than that but thats the general message.

Here's the offending part of the button javascript:

```
var queryResult = sforce.connection.query("SELECT namespaceprefix FROM ApexClass WHERE name='Ctl_Form' LIMIT 1");
```

This works fine in other orgs, any idea what setting or configuration might not allow this? I'm logged in a a System Admin.

I also tested running a SOQL query against ApexClass in the dev console and that ran fine.

Comment: is this a Group /Professional/personal edition org ?

Comment: That was my first thought... sounds like an org where Apex isn't available.

Comment: Its an EE org provisioned from the Partner Portal. If Apex wasn't available I wouldn't be able to run the SOQL query in the Dev Console right? I also double checked and I can create an Apex class in the org directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out when the package was originally installed (months ago), there were API restrictions placed on the package. I had just pushed out an upgrade this time. Those API restrictions weren't allowing access to the ApexClass object from the AJAX toolkit.

Comment: Ah yes, I love that API restrictions always remove access to system objects, and the only way to work with them is to totally turn off API restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

The user needs "View Setup and Configuration" permission to query the `ApexClass` object.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Setup**, type "users" in *Quick Find* text box. Check the User Profile name you're using to access API.
Edit the profile and set the permission **Author Apex**.
This should fix it.